# Vertically center align content of floated, dynamically heighted dv

Tags: css

I don't want to set any fixed heights to any element, is this possible?

```
<div class="floated">
  <div class="Content">
     <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML/CSS relevant code needed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height : 1000px; /* needed to let the height percentage "MyDiv" correctly work */
}
#myDiv {
  position : relative;
   height : 20%; 
  display : table;
  border : solid 1px black; /* to see the behaviour of the div, can be removed */
  
}

#myContainer {
  display : table-cell;
  vertical-align : middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="myDiv" >
  <div id="myContainer">
    my super content !
   </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Use `display : table` on a first div container, and `display : table-cell` in the sub div containing your text, or image, ....

Comment: you didn't read the op did you?